# Is it legal to use vacancies data from Stack Overflow for a personal project?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, legal

I'm about to start working on personal and non-profit pet-project, in which I'd like to collect and analyze data from different job platforms like Stack Overflow jobs or Muse, but I don't know is this legal to use mentioned web sites data, despite the fact, that it is publicly available.

Based on gathered data I'm going to build some statistics and publish results on my website.

Comment: Did you read the terms of service?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well at https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing if found `create derivative works based on` - I guess this is my case. But, How about projects which publish other statistics calculated from Q/A data - like https://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=stackoverflow&size=16 ?

Comment: Best is to also contact SO directly, they should know. But please don't write to legal@stackoverflow, because they don't give legal advice for principal reasons.

Comment: @Trilarionthan you very much for a comment. Do you mean via `Contact us` page https://stackoverflow.com/contact ? Or there is an alternative ways?